# Obtain address of first element of an array stored as an object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, managed, unsafe

I need to obtain the memory address of the first element of an array of arbitrary type, which is stored as a type of Object.  For instance the array could be a double[] or an int[], but in the code it will be typed as an Object.

While it is straightforward to obtain the address of an array of known type, obtaining an address of an object is not allowed in C#.  Is there a type (other than Object) that I could use to store such an array and whose memory address can be more easily obtained?  Or is there a way to use Interop/Reflection to access the address directly without need for an intermediate data copy?

Notice in the second line below that a double[] is stored as an object.  And notice in the fixed() line that I am trying to obtain the address of o, which is not allowed in C#.

Thanks in advance!

```
int len=100;
object o = new double [len];

   unsafe
   {
                fixed(int*ptr=&o)
                for (int index = 0; index < len; index++)
                {
                  // access data directly to copy it, etc...
                }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question (hence it is a comment), but you can probably do most of what you want by declaring a reference of type `Array` and using the `Array` class (e.g., `Array.Copy()`.

Comment: @Robert: I want to automate some of the tasks related to working with DirectCompute.  I want to bind CPU struct arrays with GPU buffers using objects that automate data copying back and forth and that reduce the amount of redundant code that I write.  There might be a better approach that I could use rather than unsafe code, but for now this will do.

Comment: @phoog: Thanks for pointing out the type Array.  I wasn't familiar with this type, and It could be helpful in the future.

Comment: Might I suggest [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654734/c-sharp-p-invoke-structure-problem) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbckfbz.aspx)?  Don't know if it's what you're looking for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`GCHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx):

```
int len=100;
object x = new long[len];
unsafe
{
    var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(x, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        void* addr = (void*)gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        // do whatever you want with addr
    }
    finally
    {
        gch.Free();
    }
}
```

Just be sure that you really need this.

Comment: Thanks!  This works.  I hate having to pin objects in the GC, but this solves my problem.  In my response to @Robert I explain what I'm trying to do.